# How can I get a list of potential methods for DefaultKeyBinding.dict?

Tags: mac, keyboard, cocoa

I would like to take more advantage of being able to define shortcuts in the Mac `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`. However I cannot find a comprehensible list of what I can remap. Right now I am searching for every bit of functionality I want to find and hope that someone already posted an answer for that. I have just found that adding

```
{
  "@\UF702" = moveWordLeft:;
  "@\UF703" = moveWordRight:;
  "@$\UF702" = moveWordLeftAndModifySelection:;
  "@$\UF703" = moveWordRightAndModifySelection:;
}
```

enables me to use <kbd>⌘←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘→</kbd> to move by word but I would like to extend this to <kbd>⌘⌫←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘⌫→</kbd> to delete forward and backward until the end of word.

I was trying to find a Apple's Cocoa documentation to get the full list of methods, but so far this is the best I could find: http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html

Any recommendations?

Comment: The only limitation would be the number of permutations of having modifiers and keys, but as far as *what* you can shortcut, you’re only limited by your imagination. Start with the [Emacs keybindings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html) because that’s what it’s based off of

Comment: @Allan I think the OP is looking for a list of potential methods they can bind keys to (e.g. `moveWordLeft` etc)

Comment: @nohillside the keybindings ate Lisp functions and that’s just one of them. You can create your own function like `moveWordLeftDoALittleDance`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can trigger any methods you want for the active view of the application you are running. [This is the most comprehensive list of methods I have found.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314030051/http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html)  It is the oldest snapshot of osxnotes.net, now down, on the wayback machine (so they may have updated it before it was taken down). See the links in the "Methods" section for even more information than the link itself provides.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, for some well-hidden, undocumented-anywhere bindable methods one may find useful like `convertToTraditionalChinese:`, you can just reverse engineer the AppKit executable by looking at its symbols. In recent OS versions the AppKit executable is no longer present on the disk, you may be able to find it in the shared cache.

For convenience, [here](https://gist.github.com/hym3242/4ade5dbcabbe547f3d78687897b8ddfehttps://)'s a dump of the 10.15 AppKit symbols.

I have also compiled some useful info in my gist [here](https://gist.github.com/hym3242/8e8bc10a2fed8e55973c500f1798c234).

Keep in mind that some key combos like option+n/u/e/`are "special" in the`keylayout` so you can't bind them in DefaultKeyBinding.dict. Some builtin input methods like SCIM have their own keylayout that override your binding, even though your bindings are able to override system default ABC keylayout. For this you may want to alter the keylayout files or create new ones with Ukulele.app.